# Which thread is used in Garbage Collection to delete the cache data?

Tags: java

In java we use Garbage Collection for cleaning the Memory.Garbage Collector is used to remove 98% of the memory,another 2% we use **finalize keyword** I wanted to know which thread is used in Garbage Collection to delete the cache data.

Comment: *another 2% we use finalize keyword*: no. Everything is managed by the garbage collector. What do you mean by "which thread"? There is at least one thread used by the GC. It's not the main thread, nor any of the threads you create.

Answer (score 2):

You get no guarantee as to which thread(s) invoke `finalize` methods, as [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.6) states:

> The Java programming language does not specify which thread will invoke the finalizer for any given object.

What's more, there's no guarantee there will be just one finalizer thread:

> Finalizers may be called in any order, or even concurrently.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, only GC is responsible for cleaning out memory. It is non-deterministic.  When the object is no longer referenced, it is suitable to be collected in the next GC run, but it is not mandated. Even calling `System.gc()` is just a suggestion to the GC system. Before removing an object from memory GC thread invokes finalize() method of that object and gives an opportunity to perform any sort of cleanup required.

Secondly, GC runs in its own daemon thread.